# Unable to enable-migrations even after following standard procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have tried following things

In package manager console.

```
  Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName  abc.DomainModel.DAL.abcDataContext -Force

 update-database -Verbose -Force

 AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```

Default project in package manager console is abc.DomainModel

And I still get this error.

"Additional information: The model backing the 'abcDataContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."

Where am I making mistake ?

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you change anything in your model classes, you need to call Update-Database from the package manager console.

So you run "Enable-migrations" one time, when you create your project, and Update-Database every time you change your Model.

Comment: In addition; when not using automatic migration, you can use `add-migration` to add the migration explicitly.

Comment: You could try to delete your Migrations folder and delete your database manually. Afterwards: Enable-Migrations    Update-database
(if you dont have any valuable data in it)